# Applet Trouble : java.lang.NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I'm having a bit of trouble with an applet using the SDK for the u.are.u 4500 biometric fingerprint reader.
When I test the applet locally using NetBeans, the applet works fine.
[image: Applet test. Local]

The problem is when I try to publish the applet.
[image: Applet web test. Error detail]

I always get the "**java.lang.NoClassDefFound**".
I modified the java configuration so that the server config and my workstation config matches.

The SDK is installed in **c:\java\jdk1.7.0_07**
The JRE is installed in **c:\java\jre7**
[image]

The jar files for the biometric fingerprint reader are:

- dpfpenrollment.jar
- dpfpverification.jar
- dpotapi.jar
- dpotjni.jar

The CLASSPATH is:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpfpenrollment.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpfpverification.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpotapi.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpotjni.jar;
```

JAVA_HOME is:

```
c:\java\jre7
```

I have tried putting the jar files in the lib folder, put the result is the same.
I googled for this error, but nothing I find helps me solve this.

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't put MySQL Connectors etc in the jre/lib/ext directory. That's not what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The CLASSPATH is:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpfpenrollment.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpfpverification.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpotapi.jar;
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dpotjni.jar;
```

No, no, no.  As mentioned by EJP, that is not what the `ext` directory is for.  Furthermore, the end users will not have those Jars in the `ext` directory, and even if they are, they will not be added to the run-time class-path of the applet.

If the applet requires those Jars, they need to be put in an accessible path on the server, while the `codebase` should point to that place and the `archive` attribute might be something like:

```
archive='mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar,dpfpenrollment.jar,dpfpverification.jar,dpotapi.jar,dpotjni.jar'
```

The MySQL jar is a bit worrying as well.  An applet should not have direct access to the DB, but that access should instead be mediated by server side functionality.  If your applet can access the DB, a malevolent user can reverse engineer it and access the DB directly.